# Confusing double precision real in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Have this burning question on my mind right now: What is the "accepted" way to declare double precision real in modern Fortran?  In order from oldest to newest, the story seems to go like this: `DOUBLE PRECISION`, then `REAL(kind=8)`, then `INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp=kind(1.d0)` with `REAL(kind=dp)`--Metcalf now says `dp=kind(0.d0)`--and now `float32=selected_real_kind(6,37)` or `float64=selected_real_kind(15,307)`. So...

1. How should I be declaring double precision real now?
2. Is `kind` redundant in `REAL(kind=dp)`?
3. Are there any special flags needed at compile time to invoke double precision real with `gfortran` or `ifort`?

Comment: I would ask what YOU mean by "double precision". The standard simply says that the precision must be greater than that of default real. If you have some specific requirement, then use SELECTED_REAL_KIND.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Personally I now write

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
```

which includes parameters such as `int32`,`real64` which have the obvious meanings, and can be used like this:

```
real(real64) :: a_64_bit_real_scalar
```

Note that `kind=8` is not guaranteed, by the standard, to deliver an 8-byte kind.  The values that kind parameters take are not standardised and do vary from compiler to compiler.

You could, if you want, write statements such as

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, dp=>real64
...
real(dp) :: a_64_bit_real_scalar
```

Comment: This is also my preference.   `real64` is a Fortran 2008 enhancement of the `iso_fortran_env`.   To me, that seems generally available, e.g., starting with gfortran 4.5.   The `iso_c_binding` types have been available longer.

Comment: Please note, that `real128` is bugged in gfortran, where it returns a 10 byte real instead of a 16 byte real. (Just in case, you need extra high precision.)

Comment: gfortran has supported true quad-precision since version 4.6 in 2011.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2011-07/msg00064.html.

Comment: I have been using the gfortran compiler option `-fdefault-real-8`, so far; now for other reason I want to use the `iso_fortran_env` module, and that option conflicts with this module's `NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE` named constant (it's just a warning, but I fear I could regret, should I ignore it). How do you suggest to act?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis what do you mean with "conflicts"

Comment: @kvantour, I mean that using the `-fdefault-real-8` compile option while the `USE`ing `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` is in some source file raises `Warning: Use of the NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE named constant from intrinsic module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV at (1) is incompatible with option -fdefault-real-8` at compile time. I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49588914/5825294) about it and received an answer.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, aha excellent way forward to ask the question. +1

Comment: How does `dp=>real64` work? I've tried it in my code and verified that it does work, but I don't understand what's going on. Is `dp` a pointer to `real64`?

Answer (score 5):

> 1)How should I be declaring double precision real now?

I personally prefer using the

```
integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(15,307)
real(wp) :: var
```

method for this. But as Mark points out, the `iso_fortran_env` is another straight-forward method. If you plan on using interfaces to C, you may want to try the [ISO_C_BINDING](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) module and use

```
use iso_c_binding
real(c_double) :: var
```

And get the double precision you want.

> 2) Is `kind` redundant in `REAL(kind=dp)`?

Yes it is.

> 3) Are there any special flags needed at compile time to invoke double precision real with `gfortran` or `ifort`?

For `gfortran` you can use the compilation flag `-fdefault-real-8`. For `ifort`, you can use the `-real-size=64` flag.

Comment: +1 for completeness, be careful though with `-fdefault-real-8`, as it promotes `double precision` to 16 bytes, consult `man gfortran` and look also at `-fdefault-double-8`.

Answer (score 0):

The current recommended way of declaring double precision reals in Fortran is:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: rk = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15, 307)
REAL(rk) :: x
...
```