# Error: If selector expression in SELECT TYPE is not a named variable, associate-name=> shall appear

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran2003

I am trying to use a type in another type. However, I just cannot make it compile. It is strange to me: the select type thing works in the main program but it doesn't work in a subroutine the type.

```
module ModBuffer
    implicit none
    private
    type, abstract, public :: Buffer
    contains
        procedure, public                       :: Constructor
    endtype Buffer

    type, extends(Buffer), public :: BufferR
        real(8), allocatable, public            :: BufData(:,:,:)
    endtype BufferR

    type, extends(Buffer), public :: BufferI
        complex(8), allocatable, public         :: BufData(:,:,:)
    endtype BufferI

    contains

    subroutine Constructor(this, dim1, dim2, dim3)
        class(Buffer), intent(inout)            :: this
        integer, intent(in)                     :: dim1, dim2, dim3

        select type(this)
        type is(BufferR)
            allocate(this%BufData(dim1, dim2, dim3))
        type is(BufferI)
            allocate(this%BufData(dim1, dim2, dim3))
        endselect
    endsubroutine Constructor
endmodule ModBuffer

module ModSystem
    use ModBuffer
    implicit none
    private
    type, public :: System
        class(Buffer), allocatable, public :: WF
    contains
    endtype System

    type, extends(System) :: NewSystem
    contains
        procedure, public :: Constructor
    endtype NewSystem

    contains

    subroutine Constructor(this, Flag)
        class(NewSystem), intent(inout) :: this
        logical, intent(in) :: Flag

        if(Flag) then
            allocate(BufferR::this%WF)
        else
            allocate(BufferI::this%WF)
        endif
        select type(this%WF)
        type is(BufferR)
            print *, "Buffer is real."
        type is(BufferI)
            print *, "Buffer is complex."
        endselect
    endsubroutine Constructor
endmodule ModSystem


program test
    use ModSystem
    !use Operation
    class(System), allocatable :: s

    allocate(NewSystem::s)
    call s%Constructor(.true.)
endprogram test
```

I got a compile error in `select type(this%WF)` line. But if I define a Buffer type in the main program and do the same thing, there would be no error.

The error message is:

```
error #8253: If selector expression in SELECT TYPE is not a named variable, associate-name=> shall appear.
```

How can I make this code compile?

Comment: I wouldn't vote this down, personally, but some people are allergic to "doesn't work" and "I got an error" without specifying how it doesn't work and how the error looks like. Noone would probably vote it down for the `real(8)`, although this is not a very sound practice.

Comment: Agreeing with Vladimir F I'll also add: there's a lot of code, is this really the simplest/most general lump that has the problem?  You say this works with a modification: what is that modification?  The exact error message is also useful: we want people with the same problem in other projects to be able to find the answer.  It's also a useful prompt for someone who does know the answer.

Comment: @VladimirF Could you please explain a bit more about "Noone would probably vote it down for the real(8)". I think real(8) is a replacement for "double precision". And I know it is much better to use a variable to specify "kind". Please tell me a bit more about your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter/841648#841648 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362211/confusing-double-precision-real-in-fortran   `kind=8` can mean something different at different platforms. Portable solutions use `select_real_kind` or `iso_fortran_env` or `iso_c_binding`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No reason to use a pointer, just use the association part of `select type` (you did not write the error message, but IIRC it is quite descriptive):

```
   select type (twf => this%WF)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this topic is vote down. But I find a solution. BTW, I am using IVF on windows (which I didn't update for several months).

It seems I cannot use member of a type in "select type" clause for triggering a IVF compiler error. But if you set a pointer to the member, everything works just fine. It is a bit wired a pointer solve the problem, and it is doesn't make much sense.

```
module ModBuffer
    implicit none
    private
    type, abstract, public :: Buffer
    contains
        procedure, public                       :: Constructor
    endtype Buffer

    type, extends(Buffer), public :: BufferR
        real(8), allocatable, public            :: BufData(:,:,:)
    endtype BufferR

    type, extends(Buffer), public :: BufferI
        complex(8), allocatable, public         :: BufData(:,:,:)
    endtype BufferI

    contains

    subroutine Constructor(this, dim1, dim2, dim3)
        class(Buffer), intent(inout)            :: this
        integer, intent(in)                     :: dim1, dim2, dim3

        select type(this)
        type is(BufferR)
            allocate(this%BufData(dim1, dim2, dim3))
        type is(BufferI)
            allocate(this%BufData(dim1, dim2, dim3))
        endselect
    endsubroutine Constructor
endmodule ModBuffer

module ModSystem
    use ModBuffer
    implicit none
    private
    type, public :: System
        class(Buffer), allocatable, public :: WF
    contains
    endtype System

    type, extends(System), public :: NewSystem
    contains
        procedure, public :: Constructor
    endtype NewSystem

    contains

    subroutine Constructor(this, Flag)
        class(NewSystem), intent(inout) :: this
        logical, intent(in) :: Flag
        class(Buffer), pointer :: P

        if(Flag) then
            allocate(BufferR::this%WF)
        else
            allocate(BufferI::this%WF)
        endif
        call SetPointer(P, this%WF)
        select type(P)
        type is(BufferR)
            print *, "Buffer is real."
        type is(BufferI)
            print *, "Buffer is complex."
        endselect
    endsubroutine Constructor

    subroutine SetPointer(MyP, MyA)
        class(Buffer), pointer :: MyP
        class(Buffer), target :: MyA
        MyP => MyA
    endsubroutine SetPointer
endmodule ModSystem


program test
    use ModSystem
    !use Operation
    class(System), allocatable :: s

    allocate(NewSystem::s)
    select type(s)
    type is(NewSystem)
        call s%Constructor(.true.)
    endselect
endprogram test
```