# Access extended type components in a SELECT TYPE construct

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, gfortran, fortran2003, allocatable-array

I'm trying to build an allocatable array with polymorphic elements. A minimal example is the following :

```
program PolyArray

implicit none

type basetype
    integer :: ib
end type basetype

type, extends(basetype) :: exttype1
    real    :: r1
end type exttype1

type, extends(exttype1) :: exttype2
    real    :: r2
end type exttype2

type arraytype
    class(basetype), allocatable :: comp
end type arraytype

type(arraytype), dimension(:), allocatable :: ary
integer :: N, i 

N = 5
allocate (ary(N))
do i=1,N; if (mod(i,2)==0) then
    allocate(exttype2::ary(i)%comp)
     else if (       i==1) then
    allocate(basetype::ary(i)%comp)
        else
    allocate(exttype1::ary(i)%comp)
end if; end do

do i=1,N; select type (this=>ary(i)%comp)
    type is (basetype)
        write(*,*) i, "is basetype"!, "%ib =", ary(i)%comp%ib
    type is (exttype1)
        write(*,*) i, "is exttype1"!, "%r1 =", ary(i)%comp%r1
    type is (exttype2)
        write(*,*) i, "is exttype2"!, "%r2 =", ary(i)%comp%r2
    class default
        write(*,*) i, "is unknown type !"
end select; end do

end program PolyArray
```

Now, the code above works fine and prints out (as expected) :

```
           1 is basetype
           2 is exttype2
           3 is exttype1
           4 is exttype2
           5 is exttype1
```

The problem is, however, once I try to access the component of each extended type (e.g. `r1` of `exttype1`) by uncommenting the commented part of each `write(*,*)` line, my compiler (gfortran 7.5.0) gives the following error :

```
         write(*,*) i, "is exttype1", "%r1 =", ary(i)%comp%r1
                                                            1
Error: 'r1' at (1) is not a member of the 'basetype' structure
poly.f90:40:60:

         write(*,*) i, "is exttype2", "%r2 =", ary(i)%comp%r2
                                                            1
Error: 'r2' at (1) is not a member of the 'basetype' structure
```

I don't understand why these errors are produced since the compiler obviously recognizes the extended types `exttype1` and `exttype2`.
What's the correct way to access `r1` and `r2`?

**EDIT :**
By changing `ary(i)%comp` to `this` in each `write(*,*)` line, the code compiles normally. What difference does this modification make? How are these two **NOT** equivalent?

Comment: Thanks a lot @francescalus! Changing `ary(i)%comp` to `this` does indeed solve my problem. I thought both would work since `this` is just a 'name tag' of `ary(i)%comp`

Comment: I originally voted to close as a typo, but now you've expanded on the confusion around `this`, I've retracted and answered.  Perhaps you can add that aspect to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the select type construct where one has

```
select type (this=>ary(i)%comp)
```

there are two things: the *selector* and the *associate name*.  `ary(i)%comp` is the selector here and `this` is the associate name.

We know that an associate name [is required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26068020/3157076) in this case, because `ary(i)%comp` is not a name.

However, the associate name isn't just for convenience (like it may be in an associate construct): it has the fundamental required property that you need here.  In the blocks governed by the type guards, the variable given by the associate name has *declared* type of the type guard; the selector retains the declared type as it had outside the construct.

Having the desired declared type allows us to access the components; simply having the dynamic type doesn't.

Comment: Thanks again, this is very well explained ! I'll edit my question to avoid further confusion