# Getting out variable from a subroutine

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have made a linear interpolation code, but when i try to get out this value in a main program or in another subroutine it displays the value of 0.0000, but when i run the program in the subroutine it gets the correct value.

write(*,*) ' Interpolverdi=', interpolverdi   gets the correct value 
 but when i run  write(*,*)'main interpolverdi',interpolverdi   i get the value of 0.0000

My input file is working perfect.

What am i doing wrong? How do you get a specific value from a subroutine and then use this value in another subroutine?

Thanks for all the help i can get :)

```
!main.f90

program mainn

use inputt
use interpoll
!use mongo

 implicit none

 integer :: n, itmax,k,bc
 real(8) :: epsilon, Re, tmax,dt,h,fux,interpolverdi
 real(8), dimension (:), allocatable :: oo,u,v,p
 integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: nn

 !real(8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: Uvel, Vvel, pres, psi


 call lesinput(n,itmax,k,epsilon,Re,tmax,dt,oo,nn,bc)



 call interpol(nn,oo,n)

 write(*,*)'main interpolverdi',interpolverdi


 end program mainn

  !interpoll.f90
 module interpoll

 implicit none

 contains


 subroutine interpol(nn,oo,n)
  integer :: nn(:), n,s,i
  real(8) :: oo(:),interpolverdi




  s = size(nn)

  do i=1,s-1

  if (n==nn(i)) then
   interpolverdi= oo(i)
  exit


 else if ((n>nn(i)) .and. (n<nn(i+1))) then
 interpolverdi= oo(i)+((oo(i+1)-oo(i))*(n-nn(i)))/(nn(i+1)-nn(i))
 exit

 else
 interpolverdi=nn(s)

 end if

end do

write(*,*) ' Interpolverdi=', interpolverdi
write(*,*)'n=',n

end subroutine interpol

 end module interpoll
```

Comment: Do not delete the code from your question. It is here for future visitors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **two distinct** variables called `interpolverdi`. One is defined in the main program and one is defined in the subroutine.

When you do `write(*,*) interpolverdi` in the main program and in the subroutine it prints a different variable each time.

If you wanted to just directly changed the main program variable from the internal subroutine, delete the declaration of `interpolverdi` from the subroutine.

A better approach however is to add another argument to your subroutine

```
 subroutine interpol(nn,oo,n,interpolverdi)
  integer :: nn(:), n,s,i
  real(8) :: oo(:),interpolverdi

end subroutine interpol
```

I recommend to rename the argument or the main program variable to something else so that they have different names.

---

BTW `real(8)` is very ugly and not completely portable. If you are learning Fortran, don't learn this **bad** habit. [Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter) [Confusing double precision real in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362211/confusing-double-precision-real-in-fortran)

Comment: how do you make them into 1 variable?  I tried  real(8), save :: interpolverdi in the interpoll.f90, that didnt work......

Comment: @ursmooth  Just delete it from the subroutine , that's all. `real(8) :: oo(:),interpolverdi` => `real(8) :: oo(:)`  But you should try to understand why is it necessary.

Comment: i fixed it now THANK YOU SO MUCH !