# ISO_FORTRAN_ENV or -fdefault-real-8 to promote reals to double precision

Tags: fortran, double, gfortran, type-promotion

I've always been using the `-fdefault-real-8` option of `gfortran` to automatically promote every single `REAL` declared anywhere in the program to double precision, **along with any constant**, *e.g.* `1.23`. If I ever wanted to switch back to single precision, I only had to remove that option and recompile, without changing a single character in the source code.

At a point I started using `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` module, since it allows me to use constants like `INPUT|OUTPUT|ERROR_UNIT`, as well as `IOSTAT_END` and `IOSTAT_EOR` and others (which seemed to be a good and easy move in the direction of portability, am I wrong?). From then on, I've been seeing and ignoring the following warning

```
Warning: Use of the NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE named constant from intrinsic module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV at (1) is incompatible with option -fdefault-real-8
```

since such incompatibility seems to have no effect so far.

Now I'd like to get rid of this warning if it is possible and worth it.

If I correctly understood, to avoid this warning I should give up on `-fdefault-real-8` option and change every `REAL` to `REAL(real64)` [and/or to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22362361/5825294) `REAL(dp)` (provided that, in the latter case, the statement `USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, dp => real64` is put in that unit), which is not a difficult task for `sed` or `vim`.

Nevertheless, it seems to me that this change wouldn't be the same as using `-fdefault-real-8` option, since **all constants would stay single precision** as long as I don't add `d0` to them.
Assumed the <strike>`-fdefault-real-8`</strike> option is removed and `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` is used anywhere, is there any way to make any constant across the program behave as each had `d0` suffix?
Whether or not this is possible, have I correctly extrapolated that I can put the following lines in a single module which is used by all others program units, each of which can then use `dp` as kind type parameter?

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = real64
```

I would prefer this way since I could switch to `real32` or `real128` or whatever by changing only that line.

Comment: The correct way is to use `1._dp` and not `1.d0` because that will be compatible with whichever way you define `dp`.

Comment: Using options like `-fdefault-real-8` should not be incompatible with the standard per se, but in standard Fortran default integer and default logical must have the same size as the default real, which is the numeric storage size.

Comment: Could I use the `NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE` constant somehow to have the same behavior of the `-fdefault-real-8` option? I mean `REAL`s **and** `1.` automatically treated as other-than-single precision.

Comment: No. BTW, did you actually searched before asking? I got https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84594 immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to silence the warning and you do not care about the implications `-fdefault-real-8` has on storage association and some Fortran standard requirements, just do not import `NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE` from the module. For example,

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only: INPUT_UNIT,OUTPUT_UNIT,ERROR_UNIT
```

Comment: Your solution seems quite immediate, but your words make me worry about _the implications `-fdefault-real-8` has on storage association and some Fortran standard requirements_. Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: Standard Fortran requires that default logical, integer and real are of the same size (the numeric storage unit). If you increase the real but not the others you are breaking this assumption and if some code relies on that it will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

> Assumed the `-fdefault-real-8` option is removed and `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` is used anywhere, is there any way to make any constant across the program behave as each had `d0` suffix?

No.

By the way, `d0` is exactly the same as `double precision`, so that doesn't fixate much either, since the meaning of `double precision` is allowed to vary as much as `real`.

> Whether or not this is possible, have I correctly extrapolated that I can put the following lines in a single module which is used by all others program units, each of which can then use dp as kind type parameter?

Yes. That is a common practice.