# Fortran Error: 'y' argument of 'datan2' intrinsic at (1) must be REAL

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to calculate z value as the coordinate in range of x:-50~50 and y:-50~50 like below code.

```
program test
implicit none
! --- [local entities]
      real*8            :: rrr,th,U0,amp,alp,Ndiv
      real*8            :: pi,alpR,NR,Rmin,Rmax,z
      integer           :: ir, i, j

do i=0, 50
  do j=0, 50
      th=datan2(i,j)
      pi=datan(1.d0)*4.d0
!
      Ndiv= 24.d0            !! Number of circumferential division
      alp = 90.d0/180.d0*pi  !! phase [rad]
      U0  = 11.4d0           !! average velocity
      amp = 0.5d0            !! amplitude of velocity
      Rmin = 10              !! [m] 
      Rmax = 50              !! [m]
      NR = 6.d0              !! Number of radial division
!
      rrr=dsqrt(i**2+j**2)
      ir=int((rrr-Rmin)/(Rmax-Rmin)*NR)
      alpR=2.d0*pi/dble(Ndiv)*dble(mod(ir,2))
      z=U0*(1.d0+amp*dsin(0.5d0*Ndiv*th+alp+alpR))

  write(*,*) 'i, j, z'
  write(*,*) i, j, z 
 end do
end do

stop
end program test
```

But I couldn't make it work like below error. I think because i, j are in datan(i,j). How should I change these code?

```
test.f90:10.16:

      th=datan2(i,j)
                1
Error: 'y' argument of 'datan2' intrinsic at (1) must be REAL
test.f90:21.16:

      rrr=dsqrt(i**2+j**2)
                1
Error: 'x' argument of 'dsqrt' intrinsic at (1) must be REAL
```

Comment: You've got to figure out how to **cast** integers to reals.

Comment: `datan2(real(i, kind(0d0)), real(j, kind(0d0)))`

Comment: Even better atan2(real(i, kind(0d0)), real(j, kind(0d0))) Specific names of intrinsic procedures shouldn't have been used for decades - I hope no one is teaching this. Similarly the completely non-standard real*8.

Comment: I couldn’t find a suitable duplicate. This is a rather trivial question, should I write a proper answer? What do you think @IanBush? Or flag it somehow?

Comment: If you can't find a duplicate write an answer - no harm done if there is one already hidden somewhere

Comment: If you can't find a duplicate with casual searching then though duplicates do not yet exist. I'd appreciate seeing an answer that explicitly addresses some of the points @Ian raises about old techniques. I've seen `real*8` frequently and didn't know it was antiquated.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the comments of @Rodrigo Rodrigues, @Ian Bush, and @Richard, here is a suggested rewrite of the code segment from @SW. Kim

```
program test
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real64
    implicit none
    ! --- [local entities]
    ! Determine the kind of your real variables (select one):
    !   for specifying a given numerical precision
    integer, parameter  :: wp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)  !15 digits, 10**307 range
    !   for specifying a given number of bits
    ! integer, parameter  :: wp = real64

    real(kind=wp), parameter    :: pi = atan(1._wp)*4._wp
    real(kind=wp)               :: rrr, th, U0, amp, alp, Ndiv
    real(kind=wp)               :: alpR, NR, Rmin, Rmax, z
    integer                     :: ir, i, j

    do i = 0, 50
        do j = 0, 50
            th = atan2(real(i, kind=wp), real(j, kind=wp))
    !
            Ndiv= 24._wp             !! Number of circumferential division
            alp = 90._wp/180._wp*pi  !! phase [rad]
            U0  = 11.4_wp            !! average velocity
            amp = 0.5_wp             !! amplitude of velocity
            Rmin = 10                !! [m]
            Rmax = 50                !! [m]
            NR = 6._wp               !! Number of radial division
    !
            rrr = sqrt(real(i, kind=wp)**2 + real(j, kind=wp)**2)
            ir = int((rrr - Rmin) / (Rmax - Rmin) * NR)
            alpR = 2._wp * pi / Ndiv * mod(ir, 2)
            z = U0 * (1._wp + amp * sin(0.5_wp * Ndiv * th + alp + alpR))
    !
            write(*,*) 'i, j, z'
            write(*,*) i, j, z
        end do
    end do

    stop
end program test
```

Specifically, the following changes were made with respect to the original code posted:

- Minimum change to answer the question: casting `integer` variables `i` and `j` to `real` values for using them in the real valued functions `datan` and `dsqrt`.
- Using generic names for intrinsic procedures, i.e `sqrt` instead of `dsqrt`, `atan` instead of `datan`, and `sin` instead of `dsin`. One benefit of this approach, is that the kind of working precision `wp` can be changed in one place, without requiring explicit changes elsewhere in the code.
- Defining the `kind` of `real` variables and calling it `wp`. Extended discussion of this topic, its implications and consequences can be found on this site, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362211/confusing-double-precision-real-in-fortran) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter/856243#856243). Also @Steve Lionel has an in depth post on his [blog](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2017/03/27/doctor-fortran-in-it-takes-all-kinds), where his general advice is to use `selected_real_kind`.
- Defining `pi` as a `parameter` calculating its value once, instead of calculating the same value repeatedly within the nested for loops.

Comment: _sniped_. Good answer, +1. By the way, in `real(mod(ir, 2), kind=wp)`, the convention to real is unnecessary.